# Аналог flex-grow:1; для блока без высоты

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

Есть простой пример: https://codesandbox.io/s/color-c4wos0?file=/src/styles.css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном примере с flex-grow:1; Блок занимает все свободное для него пространство, то есть от Header до Footer. При этом у этого блока не указана высота. Даже если мы вставим туда картинку, через background, она адаптивно впишется, и будет менять размер адаптивно, и подстраиваться под это свободное пространство.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же убрать это свойство, то у блока не будет высоты и ширины, так как в нем нет контента, и размер явно не указан, но мне нужно, чтобы он, так же занимал все доступное для него пространство, как раньше, но без свойства flex-grow:1. Есть ли альтернативные варианты flex-grow:1?

Т.к. этот способ может вызвать проблемы, если допустим, кто-то задаст flex-grow у другого блока.

Comment: При родителе `display: grid` можно задать `grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr max-content` и второй ряд, то есть в вашем случае красный блок будет на всю доступную высоту.

Answer (score -1):

Уже был такой вопрос - [Как растянуть div на всю высоту экрана так, чтобы тот находился под шапкой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172215/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-div-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9)

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.color {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
}

.footer {
  height: var(--bs-header-footer-height);
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="App">
    <div class="header">
      <span>Header</span>
    </div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="footer">
      <span>Footer</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Данный ответ подходит только под мой простой пример с codesandbox, но при этом не отвечает на вопрос, как растянуть блок без высоты, на все доступное ему пространство.

Это не 2 одинаковых вопроса, а 2 принципиально разных. В моем случае меня интересует поведение  `flex-grow:1` для любого блока без высоты, и его аналоги. А в скинутом тобой вопросе, человеку просто нужно растянуть блок под шапкой, то есть он строго привязывается к разметке, а значит имеет строго указанную высоту у блока.

Comment: @Nick  Где вы увидели строго указанную высоту? Блок "color" растягивается на всю высоту экрана не зависимо от количества контента, как раз что вы и хотели. Просили альтернативу, вот же она.